# mosMainBody not displaying com_content

Tags: templates, joomla, deprecated

On an old Joomla installation (version 1.0.13), I've been asked to come in fresh and see if I can figure this out.

Everything is working ok and permissions are set correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This error is mostly due because of a "too new" PHP Version (newer than 5.3.x) on old Joomla installations.

One workaround is to downgrade your PHP Version.

Another, in case you are not too keen to upgrade your Joomla version or downgrade your PHP version, is:

- Go to `[webroot]includes/Cache/Lite/Function.php`.

and Find

```
$arguments = func_get_args();a
```

Replace it with the following code:

```
$arguments = func_get_args();
$numargs = func_num_args();
for($i=1; $i < $numargs; $i++)
{
  $arguments[$i] = &$arguments[$i];
}
```